# Disabling Cache-Control in Nginx for certain IPs

Tags: nginx, cache-control

Static files on my server served with browser caching via Cache-Control headers:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Is it possible to disable this header for certain IPs so they would not cache any files?

P.S. I need it for users who log in as administrators to see the last changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expires` directive can be controlled by a variable, usually generated by a `map` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.

For example:

```
map $remote_addr $expires {
    default     1h;
    10.1.2.3    -1;
}
server {
    ...
    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires    $expires;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
}
```

It is assumed that the `add_header` statements can remain, even if `expires` is set to `-1` to disable the caching.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.